# java: usage of instance keyword

Tags: java, oop

i came across to a java code with like this

```
public class TestClass{

  private static volatile TestClass instance = null;
  ///...............

}
```

What is the use of `instance` and volotile in java, and i don't know why do we need to explicitly give null value to class.

Comment: `instance` is not a keyword. It's just the name of the variable that is of type `TestClass`.

Comment: `instance` is not a keyword, it's a variable name in this case. This is very common for `Singleton` pattern classes.

Comment: Looks like a singleton implementation. There probably isn't really any need to declare it as null, but it makes the intention obvious

Comment: instance is variable!!! class and null value (whats that)??

Comment: There is an `instanceof` keyword, so that might be where the confusion is coming from. But as the others pointed out, its just a name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This variable is meant to be used in a threadpool.
here is the definition of the volatile keyword:

http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile.shtml